# Activate-noawait ldconfig trigger for runtime library package

Tags: linux, shared-library, debian-policy

I'm reading [the Debian policy section on runtime shared library package](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-sharedlibs.html#s-sharedlibs-runtime) and came across the following statement:

> Any package installing shared libraries in one of the default library 
>   directories of the dynamic linker (which are currently `/usr/lib` and 
>   `/lib`) or a directory that is listed in `/etc/ld.so.conf` [5] must use 
>   `ldconfig` to update the shared library system.
>
> Any such package must have the line `activate-noawait ldconfig` in 
>   its triggers control file (i.e. `DEBIAN/triggers`).

I'm curious of what can happen if I forget to add such trigger. Currently I have a dev package installed without any triggers and a binary linked against the library works just fine.

Why does the requirement matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement matters because `ld.so` uses a cache to resolve libraries, and `ldconfig` updates that cache. You can view its contents by running

```
/sbin/ldconfig -p
```

If you skip the trigger, without running `ldconfig` in your `postinst` either (which is what library packages used to be required to do), the cache won’t be updated.

This doesn’t concern `-dev` packages because they don’t install runtime libraries. They typically depend on a library package which will have the trigger.

When developing a package, this is usually taken care of transparently by the build tools. For example, if you use `debhelper` or anything depending on that, the build will normally end up running `dh_makeshlibs` which will add the trigger if necessary.